# How to get meaningful content using BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have some code to extract body from a webpage like this:-

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
content=requests.get('https://www.someurl.com')
soup=BeautifulSoup(content.content, 'html.parser')
bodyContent=soup.select('body')[0].getText()
print(bodyContent)
```

This code works well. But if body is something like that:-

```
<script>var x='something'; //and much more stuffs</script><h1>Body of the webpage</h1>
```

Then the result is:-

```
var x='something'; //and much more stuffs Body of the webpage
```

I want to only get content inside **div**, **span**, **p** and all other **meaningful** content. I want to ignore script tag and any code related tag.
What's the solution for it?

Comment: Hi, you should to extract your tag before use it, using extract method `[s.extract() for s in soup('script')]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, the loop should remove any 'script' or 'style' tags picked up. 
Just configure for any tags you want to ignore:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
content=requests.get('https://www.someurl.com')
soup=BeautifulSoup(content.content, 'html.parser')

for elem in soup(["script", "style"]):
    elem.decompose()

bodyContent=soup.select('body')[0].getText()
print(bodyContent)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solutions, write a simple utility function as below and use the **extract** method.

```
def clean(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    for script in soup(["script", "style"]): # remove all script and style tags
        script.extract()
    return soup.get_text()
```